# Are the times listed in The Castle Guide in weeks or days?

Tags: adnd-2e, time

In The Castle Guide supplement page 54 is a table detailing several building types and their associated costs and requirements. Are the values under the column for build time meant to represent person-weeks or person-days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Person-Weeks, or "man/weeks" as the guide calls it.

These numbers are later given units as the guide explains how to put everything together. We see in section 5.7.4:

> Eight small, square tower modules cost a total of
> 112,000 gold pieces to build and require 6,720 man/weeks
> of work.

From the table, one square tower module is given 840 units of time, so 8 of them would be 6720, which the above quote defines as man/weeks.

Comment: Technically it is \$\frac{t_{weeks}}{N_{men}}\$, as by doubling the number of workers, you halve the time it takes and vice versa.